# Column Mapping using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes , the first one has 1000 rows and looks like:

```
    Date        tri23_1   hsgç_T2   bbbj-1Y_jn   Family       Bonus
2011-06-09      qwer        1           rits      Laavin        456
2011-07-09       ww         43          mayo      Grendy        679
2011-09-10       wwer       44          ramya     Fantol        431
2011-11-02                  5           sam       Gondow        569
```

The second dataframe contains all the unique values and also the hotels, that are associated to these values:

```
Group             Hotel
tri23_1           Jamel
hsgç_T2           Frank
bbbj-1Y_jn        Luxy
mlkl_781          Grand Hotel
vchs_94           Vancouver
```

My goal is to replace the columns of the first dataframe by the the corresponding values of the column Hotel of the second dataframe and the output should look like below:-

```
    Date        Jamel     Frank           Luxy     Family       Bonus
2011-06-09      qwer        1           rits       Laavin        456
2011-07-09       ww         43          mayo       Grendy        679
2011-09-10       wwer       44          ramya      Fantol        431
2011-11-02                  5           sam        Gondow        569
```

Can i achieve this using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, using [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df1.columns=[df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()['Hotel'][i] if i in df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()['Hotel'].keys() else i for i in df1.columns]
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
df1
         Date tri23_1 hsgç_T2 bbbj-1Y_jn  Family  Bonus
0  2011-06-09    qwer       1       rits  Laavin  456.0
1  2011-07-09      ww      43       mayo  Grendy  679.0
2  2011-09-10    wwer      44      ramya  Fantol  431.0
3  2011-11-02               5        sam  Gondow  569   

df2
        Group        Hotel
0     tri23_1        Jamel
1     hsgç_T2        Frank
2  bbbj-1Y_jn         Luxy
3    mlkl_781  Grand Hotel
4     vchs_94    Vancouver

df1 changed
         Date Jamel Frank    Luxy  Family  Bonus
0  2011-06-09  qwer     1    rits  Laavin  456.0
1  2011-07-09    ww    43    mayo  Grendy  679.0
2  2011-09-10  wwer    44   ramya  Fantol  431.0
3  2011-11-02          5      sam  Gondow  569
```

**Update: Explanation**

First, if `df2['Group']` isn't the index of df2, we set it as index.

Then pass the dataframe to a dict:

```
df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()

>>>{'Hotel': {'tri23_1': 'Jamel', 'hsgç_T2': 'Frank', 'bbbj-1Y_jn': 'Luxy', 'mlkl_781': 'Grand Hotel', 'vchs_94': 'Vancouver'}}
```

Then we select the value of key `'Hotel'`

```
df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()['Hotel']

>>>{'tri23_1': 'Jamel', 'hsgç_T2': 'Frank', 'bbbj-1Y_jn': 'Luxy', 'mlkl_781': 'Grand Hotel', 'vchs_94': 'Vancouver'}
```

Then column by column we search its value in that dictionary, and if such column doesn't exit in the keys of the dictionary, we just return the same value e.g. Date, Family, Bonus:

```
i='Date'
i in df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()['Hotel'].keys --->False
return 'Date'
...
i='tri23_1'
i in df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()['Hotel'].keys --->True
return df2.set_index('Group').to_dict()['Hotel']['tri23_1']
...
...
#And so on...
```